# Can I host multiple versions of ASP.NET Core websites at the same time on IIS server

Tags: asp.net-core, iis

ASP.NET Core 6 is here and I made a new website using it, but now I would like to host it on the same server that one of my other websites uses and it is run by ASP.NET Core 3.1, can I host multiple different versions of ASP.NET Core on the same server?

Thanks in advance
Best regards Max

Comment: If you use out-of-process hosting and self contained deployment together, then it should work flawlessly. But upgrading all to .NET 6 is more beneficial

Comment: Yes, you even don’t need to have the framework installed in the server if you use self contained deployment.

Comment: You can use self-hosted deployments as they say, which doesn't require additional configuration of the framework. Otherwise you need to install different versions of .NET SDK and Runtime in the device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had problems running 2 versions at the same time but you can, it works if you install both 3.1 and 6.

Comment: did you have two different hosting bundles installed on the same machine?